# Continuous call on EventListener on mousedown

Tags: javascript, toggle, event-listener, mousedown

I'm working on an Etch A Sketch app for The Odin Project and I want to adjust one of the requirements where all I need to do is move the mouse on screen as a continuous stroke where each pixel touched on mouseover is filled, which is what's happening right now with my code.

What I want to change is the `mouseover` on my tile EventListener where it's really a continuous stroke on `mousedown`.  I did try changing the `e.target` command in the `setTiles` function to `toggle` after changing the `tile.addEventListener` to `mousedown`, but it only works on each press of the left mouse button.

I'm trying to figure out a way to make this continuous on `mousedown` instead of using `mouseover`.  I've included the code I have so far in the question.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
const userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');
let penDown = false;

grid.style.fontSize = '1em';
// Set pixel width and height
let wdt = '1em';
let hgt = '1em';

// Ask the user for the number of tiles for the sketch grid
function getUserInput() {
  let input = parseInt(prompt(`Please enter the grid size you'd like`));
  input <= 100 || !isNaN(input)
    ? createSketchGrid(input)
    : alert('Please enter a valid number less than or equal to 100.');
}

// Event listener to create tiles in mouseover
function setTiles(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('fill');
}

// function deleteTiles(e) {
//   e.target.classList.toggle('fill');
// }

container.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  penDown = true;
});

container.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  penDown = false;
});

// Create the grid
function createSketchGrid(tiles) {
  let gridSize = tiles * tiles;
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.style.width = wdt;
    tile.style.height = hgt;
    grid.appendChild(tile);
    // tile.addEventListener('mouseover', setTiles, false);
    if ((penDown === true)) {
      tile.addEventListener('mousemove', setTiles);
    }
  }
}

userInput.addEventListener('click', getUserInput);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.grid {
  /* font-size: 1.6rem; */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 0 0 32em;
}

.fill {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <button id="user-input" class="btn user-input" value="Grid Size">Grid Size</button>
    <div id="grid" class="grid">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add an onmousedown and onmouseup listener to the container element. These listeners will set an external variable (like `penDown = true;` and `penDown = false;`). Now use this variable inside your onmousemove listener to make the cell black (or not).

Comment: @ChrisG I did update the code and added a penDown variable and initialized to false. I then added two eventListeners on the container which set penDown to true if there is a mousedown event on the container and false if there is a mouseup event on the container. Now, the createSketchGrid function checks to see if penDown is true and fires the mousemove listener on tile, but nothing happens when the cursor moves around the page.

Comment: You're *adding the event listener* based on the variable. That's like crossing the road based on what the traffic light showed that one time years ago when you learned about traffic lights. You need to do the penDown check *inside the setTiles function*. Also note that `if (penDown)` is enough, testing against `== true` is completely redundant